# How to get comments(message) count on particular yammer feed or paticular URL.?

Tags: yammer

I have integrated yammer feed in my project now I need to get count of the comments made on the particular page(URL).

```
yam.connect.embedFeed({
container: '#yammer-feed'
,network: ''
,feedType: 'open-graph'
,feedId: ''
,config: {
use_sso: false
, header: true
, footer: true
, showOpenGraphPreview: false
, defaultToCanonical: false
, hideNetworkName: false,
hideAttachmentContainer: true
},
objectProperties:{
url: "*someurl*",
type: page 
}
});
```

I need to know how to get the count of all comments(messages) for this particular URL mentioned in objectProperties above.
Is there any yammer API to get the count, can anyone help with this?

Comment: were you able to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

There is an API call to get messages for an open graph object.  I've used it to get all of the messages and just enumerated through them for a count.  You'll first need to get the Open Graph ID of the page and then pass that ID into the messages API.

```js
//see if we have an OG object for the current page.
yam.platform.request(
  { url: "https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/open_graph_objects?url="+pageURL
  , method: "GET"
  , data: { "body": "This Post was Made Using the Yammer API.  Welcome to the Yammer API World." }
  , success: function (msg) {
       //OG object exists. 
       ogID = msg.id;
       
    }
  , error: function (msg) { 
      //OG object doesn't exist, we need to creat it.
    }
});
```

Then pass in the Open Graph object ID to the messages API

```js
//gets the comments count for the OpenGraph object
   var commentCnt = 0;
   yam.platform.request(
    { url: "https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/messages/open_graph_objects/"+ogID+".json"
    , method: "GET"
    , data: {"body": "This Post was Made Using the Yammer API.  Welcome to the Yammer API World."}
    , success: function (msg) {
     if (msg) {
            jQuery.each(msg.messages, function (index, element) {
       commentCnt++;
            });
        }
     //adds the count to the webpage.
           jQuery("div#commentCnt").text(commentCnt);
      }
    , error: function (msg) { 
        //console.log("message lookup failed");
     }
   });
```

Comment: I tried using your code but it returns only recent 20 messages not more than that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25003722/yammer-rest-api-message-comments-and-message-history

Comment: and I need to get total messages count for that particular URL.

Comment: Looks like Yammer limits it to 20 messages.  Check this post out for ideas on how to get more than 20 by using the Older_than and pages. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20538349/yammer-json-feed-returning-only-20-messages

Comment: I tried this code. But it returns "xmlhttprequest cannot load the url. No 'Acess-control-origin' header is present on the requested resource

Answer (score 0):

It is not a documented API call, but I managed to get the group update count with this request:

GET - https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/networks/current?include_group_counts=true